# Vue: Preload image with new Image / Transform Directive to Methode

Tags: vue.js, onload

It seems to be simple, but somehow I fail to complete.

I want to preload images in my nuxt app, like in this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pespantelis/pen/RWVZxL/) but not as a directive, cause I only use it in one component.

It works fine, like this in a picture tag.

```
<img
  v-img-preloader="require(`@/assets/img/placeholder.png`)"
  v-if="lastImage"
  v-lazy="longUrlWithStuff"
  :alt="altTitle"
  :class="classNameInner"
/>
```

(The directive v-img-preloader is on every  as well.)

And the directive itselft is:

```
Vue.directive('img-preloader', {
  bind: function (el, binding) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = binding.value;

    img.onload = function () {
      el.src = binding.value;
    }
  }
})
```

But now, I do not know, how to transform this, into a method or mounted hook. I would prefer a method, but do not know, how and what to pass an "el" for this element.
I saw, that [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrndwgn/bjn9yekw/4/) and tried it like there, with a mounted hook, but stuck ...

```
  mounted() {
    let img = new Image();

    img.src = require(`@/assets/img/placeholder.png`);

    img.onload = () => {
      this.src = require(`@/assets/img/placeholder.png`);
    };
  },
```

I appreciate, if anybody with a clue, sees, what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.